# Using newcommand in multiple subfiles with standalone

Tags: macros, standalone

So I am using the package `standalone` to combine multiple separate files. In each subfile, I define a new command (its the same in each subfile). The problem is when I used standalone to combine the two subfiles, I get an error relating to redefining the command.

Main file:

```
\documentclass[class=article,float=true,crop=false, paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,twocolumn]{standalone}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{import}

\begin{document}
    \import{1/}{1}
    \import{2/}{2}
\end{document}
```

Subfile1:

```
\documentclass[class=article,float=true,crop=false,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,twocolumn]{standalone}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\newcommand{\opt}{\text{OPT}}

\begin{document}
    Subfile 1 $\opt$
\end{document}
```

Subfile2:

```
\documentclass[class=article,float=true,crop=false,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,twocolumn]{standalone}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\newcommand{\opt}{\text{OPT}}

\begin{document}
    Subfile 2 $\opt$
\end{document}
```

When compiling, the following error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \opt already defined.
```

Comment: You could use `\providecommand` instead of `\newcommand`.

Answer (score 2):

### Approach 1:

As Skillmon already said you can use `\providecommand` instead of `\newcommand`.

(With `\providecommand` attempts at defining the macro in question take place only in case it is not already defined.)

### Approach 2:

The standalone-manual says that `document`-environments of imported files are treated as local scopes/groups.

Therefore you can restrict the definition of `\opt` to the scope of a `document`-environment by putting it inside the `document`-environment. I know you usually don't perform `\newcommand` inside a `document`-environment but you can do it:

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass[class=article,float=true,crop=false, paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,twocolumn]{standalone}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{import}

\begin{document}
    \import{1/}{1}
    \import{2/}{2}
\end{document}
```

**/1/1.tex**

```
\documentclass[class=article,float=true,crop=false,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,twocolumn]{standalone}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    % have defining performed inside the document-environment:
    \newcommand{\opt}{\text{OPT 1}}%
    Subfile 1 $\opt$
\end{document}
```

**/2/2.tex**

```
\documentclass[class=article,float=true,crop=false,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,twocolumn]{standalone}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    % have defining performed inside the document-environment:
    \newcommand{\opt}{\text{OPT 2}}%
    Subfile 2 $\opt$
\end{document}
```

Of course this approach works out only with macros that are not used outside the scope of a document-environment. I.e.: **Tokens whose defining took place within a document-environment should not go unexpanded into moving arguments** like referencing-labels or section-headings or `\caption`s!

### Approach 3:

In situations where all files are to use exactly the same preamble and postamble I don't use packages like standalone or subfiles at all but keep preamble and postamble in separate files and have LaTeX maintain a counter for keeping track of the nesting-level of `\input` with things that might need a postamble in case the nesting-level of `\input` is 0.
In case the preamble was already loaded and thus the `\documentclass`-command was redefined to be equal to `\@twoclasseserror`, processing preamble.tex is aborted prematurely via `\endinput` after incrementing the counter for the input-nesting-level.
In case the counter for the input-nesting-level is larger than 0, processing postamble.tex is aborted prematurely via `\endinput` after decrementing the counter for the input-nesting-level.

**./preamble.tex**

```
\expandafter\ifx\csname @twoclasseserror\endcsname\documentclass
  \stepcounter{preambleinputcounter}%
  \expandafter\endinput
\fi
%
% The preamble:
%
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\newcounter{preambleinputcounter}
% import – establish input relative to a directory
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\opt}{\text{OPT}}%
\begin{document}%
```

**./postamble.tex**

```
\ifnum\number\value{preambleinputcounter}>0 %
  \addtocounter{preambleinputcounter}{-1}%
  \expandafter\endinput
\fi
%
% The "postamble":
%
\end{document}%
```

**./main.tex**

```
\input{./preamble.tex}%
\import{./1/}{1}
\import{./2/}{2}
\input{./postamble.tex}%
```

**./1/1.tex**

```
\input{../preamble.tex}%
Subfile 1 $\opt$
\input{../postamble.tex}%
```

**./2/2.tex**

```
\input{../preamble.tex}%
Subfile 2 $\opt$
\input{../postamble.tex}%
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your desired end-result is - if you want to integrate the PDFs generated from `Subfile1` and `Subfile2`, or you're simply splitting your `.tex` file into multiple sub-files. (I assume you're doing the latter, but correct me if I'm wrong).

It would be much easier on your part if you use the `input{}` command, as then you only have a single preamble that every `.tex` file you later combine in your project can access.

As a result, your project would look like:

**Main file**

```
\documentclass[class=article,float=true,crop=false, paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,twocolumn]{standalone}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}

% global declaration of command - can be used in any file called by \input
\newcommand{\opt}{\text{OPT}}

\begin{document}
    \input{Subfile1.tex}
    
    \input{Subfile2.tex}
\end{document}
```

**Subfile1.tex** (note that these files require no preamble whatsoever)

```
Subfile 1 $\opt$
```

**Subfile2.tex**

```
Subfile 2 $\opt$
```

which gives you the result

[image]

Comment: But the thing is that I need to subfiles to be compiled separately, so they need a preamble.

Comment: Oh, I see. Your problem then is that the command `\import` doesn't import the compiled PDFs - it imports the `.tex` code which is why you get your error, as the code seen from the compiler has two `\newcommand{}` lines. You want to instead import the PDFs into your document, which you can do with a package like `pdfpages`.

Comment: How would that work in regards with page numbering? Like if the imported pages already have page numbers.

Comment: In your case I don't think they would, as you're generating them as `standalone` documents. Regardless, you could clear the headers and footers (which would remove the page numbers) using a package like `fancyhdr`.